# Android, start a new activity and pass it a variable

Tags: android, variables, android-activity

I want to start a new activity with a variable passed in it.

Code so far:

```
if(mostLikelyThingHeard.toUpperCase().equals("PLAY ONE"))
{
    startActivity(new Intent("com.shaz.new"));
    //I want to send an int value `1` to the new activity.
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: this how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: Honestly, this is very basic Android... I would suggest you start reading developer Training section (http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `putExtra(key, value)`

Do like this

```
 if(mostLikelyThingHeard.toUpperCase().equals("PLAY ONE"))
    {
    Intent i=new Intent("com.shaz.new");
     i.putExtra("key","value")
    startActivity(i);
    }
```

**Retrieve:**

`int value =getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0);` 0 is default value

Comment: should i replace value with "1" ??

Comment: @ShivamBansal Without any doubt..

Comment: and how can i retrieve this in new activity ? Thank you very much

Comment: @ShivamBansal posted that..

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there have two class one A and another one is B. You want to pass some data from A to B.

**FROM CLASS A :**

```
Intent result = new Intent(A.this,B.class);

result.putExtra("videoId", videoId);

result.putExtra("title",titleEdit.getText().toString());

result.putExtra("des", descriptionEdit.getText().toString());

result.putExtra("gps", passingGPS);

startActivity(result);
```

By above code you have start B activity from A and have passed some data. When B activity will start you have to get those data which you have passed in the time of calling B class from A class. You have to follow like this way to get the value of A class which you have passed.

**From Class B:**

```
VideoID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoId");

GPS = getIntent().getExtras().getString("gps");

Description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("des");

Title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
```

Now you will able to use those value in class B.

Hope this will help you to "Start a new activity with passing some data".